# Android: JSON parsing error

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

I am getting error in my app. I am doing the JSON parsing. The parsing is ok, but where is the issue occurs i am not getting.

My JSON is:

```
{"status":1,
        "magazines":[{
            "magazinetitle": "Test Magazine 1",
            "magazineid": 100,
            "magazinecoverthumburl": "pages/page1.jpg",
            "magazinecoverlargeurl": "pages/page1.jpg",
            "pages":[{
                "pagenumber": 1,
                "thumburl":"pages/page1.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page1.jpg",
                "subpages": [{
                                "pagenumber": 1,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 2,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 3,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 4,
                                "pagetype": "image"
                            }]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 2,
                "thumburl":"pages/page2.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page2.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 3,
                "thumburl":"pages/page3.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page3.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 4,
                "thumburl":"pages/page4.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page4.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 5,
                "thumburl":"pages/page5.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page5.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 6,
                "thumburl":"pages/page6.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page6.jpg",
                "subpages": [{
                                "pagenumber": 1,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 2,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 3,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 4,
                                "pagetype": "image"
                            }]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 7,
                "thumburl":"pages/page7.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page7.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 8,
                "thumburl":"pages/page8.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page8.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 9,
                "thumburl":"pages/page15.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page15.jpg",
                "subpages": [{
                                "pagenumber": 1,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 2,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 3,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 4,
                                "pagetype": "image"
                            }]
            },              
            {
                "pagenumber": 10,
                "thumburl":"pages/page8.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page8.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            }]
        },
        {
            "magazinetitle": "Test Magazine 2",
            "magazineid": 101,
            "magazinecoverthumburl": "pages/page2.jpg",
            "magazinecoverlargeurl": "pages/page2.jpg",
            "pages":[{
                "pagenumber": 1,
                "thumburl":"pages/page1.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page1.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 2,
                "thumburl":"pages/page2.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page2.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 3,
                "thumburl":"pages/page3.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page3.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 4,
                "thumburl":"pages/page4.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page4.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 5,
                "thumburl":"pages/page5.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page5.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 6,
                "thumburl":"pages/page6.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page6.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 7,
                "thumburl":"pages/page7.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page7.jpg",
                "subpages": [{
                                "pagenumber": 1,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 2,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 3,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 4,
                                "pagetype": "image"
                            }]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 8,
                "thumburl":"pages/page13.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page13.jpg",
                "subpages":[]
            },
            {
                "pagenumber": 9,
                "thumburl":"pages/page14.jpg",
                "largeurl":"pages/page14.jpg",
                "subpages": [{
                                "pagenumber": 1,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 2,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 3,
                                "pagetype": "video"
                            },
                            {
                                "pagenumber": 4,
                                "pagetype": "image"
                            }]
            }]
        // And so on magazine, pages, subpages are there...
        }]}
```

My code is of do in background is as follows:

Global Variable is

```
// contacts JSONArray
public static JSONArray status = null, magazines = null, pages = null, subpages = null;
```

doInBackground(Void... arg0) code:

```
// Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                status = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_MAGAZINES);

                Magazine magazine1 = new Magazine();                    

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < status.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject magazine = status.getJSONObject(i);                      

                    String magazineTitle = magazine.getString(TAG_MAGAZINETITLE);
                    magazine1.setMagazineTitle(magazineTitle);
                    magazine1.setMagazineid(String.valueOf(magazine.getInt(TAG_MAGAZINEID)));
                    magazine1.setMagazinecoverthumburl(magazine.getString(TAG_MAGAZINECOVERTHUMBURL));
                    magazine1.setMagazinecoverlargeurl(magazine.getString(TAG_MAGAZINECOVERLARGEURL));

                    String magazineCoverThumbURL = magazine.getString(TAG_MAGAZINECOVERTHUMBURL);
                    String magazineCoverLargeURL = magazine.getString(TAG_MAGAZINECOVERLARGEURL);*/

                    JSONObject jsonObjInnerString = status.getJSONObject(i);
                    pages = jsonObjInnerString.getJSONArray(TAG_PAGES);
                    Pages pagesModel = new Pages();

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int j = 0; j < pages.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject pagesObject = pages.getJSONObject(j);

                        pagesModel.setPagenumber(String.valueOf(pagesObject.getInt(TAG_PAGENUMBER)));
                        pagesModel.setThumburl(pagesObject.getString(TAG_THUMBURL));
                        pagesModel.setLargeurl(pagesObject.getString(TAG_LARGEURL));
                        magazine1.setPages(pagesModel);

                        JSONObject jsonObjSubInnerString = pages.getJSONObject(j);
                        subpages = jsonObjSubInnerString.getJSONArray(TAG_SUBPAGES);

                        SubPages subPagesModel = new SubPages();

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int k = 0; k < subpages.length(); k++) {
                            Log.d("k",String.valueOf(k));

                            JSONObject subPagesObject = subpages.getJSONObject(k);

                            subPagesModel.setSubpagenumber(String.valueOf(subPagesObject.getInt(TAG_SUBPAGENUMBER)));
                            Log.d("SPgno",String.valueOf(subPagesObject.getInt(TAG_SUBPAGENUMBER)));
                            subPagesModel.setSubpagetype(subPagesObject.getString(TAG_SUBPAGETYPE));
                            subPagesModel.setSubpageurl(subPagesObject.getString(TAG_SUBPAGEURL));
                            pagesModel.setSubPages(subPagesModel);
                        }
                    }

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> magazineDetailsHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    magazineDetailsHashMap.put(TAG_MAGAZINETITLE, magazineTitle);
                    //magazineDetailsHashMap.put(TAG_MAGAZINEID, magazineID);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    magazineDetails.add(magazine1);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
```

And the code of magzine class is as follows:

```
int count = MainActivity.status.length(),l=0;
public String[] magazineTitle = new String[count], magazineid = new String[count], magazinecoverthumburl = new String[count], magazinecoverlargeurl = new String[count];
public Pages[] pages = new Pages[count];
public String[] getMagazineTitle() {
    return magazineTitle;
}
public void setMagazineTitle(String magazineTitle) {
    this.magazineTitle[l] = magazineTitle;
}
public String[] getMagazineid() {
    return magazineid;
}
public void setMagazineid(String magazineid) {
    this.magazineid[l] = magazineid;
}
public String[] getMagazinecoverthumburl() {
    return magazinecoverthumburl;
}
public void setMagazinecoverthumburl(String magazinecoverthumburl) {
    this.magazinecoverthumburl[l] = magazinecoverthumburl;
}
public String[] getMagazinecoverlargeurl() {
    return magazinecoverlargeurl;
}
public void setMagazinecoverlargeurl(String magazinecoverlargeurl) {
    this.magazinecoverlargeurl[l] = magazinecoverlargeurl;
}
public Pages[] getPages() {
    return pages;
}
public void setPages(Pages pages) {
    this.pages[l] = pages;
    l++;
}
```

Error is as follows:

```
2-27 12:01:12.255: W/dalvikvm(15169): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at com.oi.jsonparsingnestingdemo.model.Magazine.setPages(Magazine.java:37)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at com.oi.jsonparsingnestingdemo.MainActivity$GetMagazineDetails.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:137)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at com.oi.jsonparsingnestingdemo.MainActivity$GetMagazineDetails.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
02-27 12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: what is error? do you have logcat?

Comment: post the stacktrace along with the line where that error occurs.

Comment: @Bhumika: I edited my post with logcat.

Comment: may be you can change the type of page array to arraylist because you have to made it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 02-27
>   12:01:12.255: E/AndroidRuntime(15169):    at
>   com.oi.jsonparsingnestingdemo.model.Magazine.setPages(Magazine.java:37)

It seems that when setting your pages the inner array `pages` might not be initialized correctly. Please check if `int count = MainActivity.status.length();` returns the value you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

Even though the first answer might help you I would definitely advise you towards using json parsing libraries. In this particluar case I use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

in Magazine.java:

```
public class Magazine {
 private String magazinetitle;
 private int magazineid;
 private String magazinecoverthumburl;
 private String magazinecoverlargeurl;
 private List<Page> pages;
 // declare getters for the same fields if you need to read them
 // Setters are not a requirement
}
```

in Response.java

```
public class Response{
 private int status;
 private List<Magazine> magazines;
 // declare getters for the same fields if you need to read them
 // Setters are not a requirement
}
```

Actually you can happily live without this class and combine `JSONObject` and GSON parsing, but now `JSONObject` approach seems so cumbersome to me.

Now your `doInBackground` turns to be:

```
// Making a request to url and getting response
String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST);
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.parse(jsonStr , Response.class);
```

This will fill in all the fields you need. I am not kidding. You do not need to make any manual parsing yourself. You will not have any way to cause an error.

For more advanced usage you can also use the `@SerializedName` annotation to make the java fields be beautifully camelCased rather than confusinggly several words in the same case.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be as Boris Strandjev pointed out, to use GSON. 
If you want to avoid using the library and continue doing the parsing yourself you could:

```
setPages(Pages pages)
{
if(pages.length >= l-1)
return;
this.pages[l] = pages;
    l++;
}
```

This should prevent you app from crashing.
You should pass the page count in the Magazine constructor and not access it statically.

Answer (score 0):

@MarioStoilov answer is the correct one. He is pointing you in the right direction. 
You are crashing because of an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException due to:

```
int count = MainActivity.status.length();//is the issue
```

Your crash is happening because of:

```
public void setPages(Pages pages) { //by the way. here, I would change "Pages pages" to "Pages  page" because your getting one page from the many pages
    this.pages[l] = pages;
    l++;
}
```

Why?....

Well lets say you do this:

```
int count =0;
public Pages[] pages = new Pages[count];
```

Then you try to do this:

```
Pages onePage = pages[0];
```

You will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. To ask for and item out of "pages[]" it will at lest need to have one item in it. It does not matter if the item is empty. it still needs to have one. The only way your code will work is if  count is = or > 1. NEVER 0

```
 int count =1;//this MUST be greater then 0 never never 0 or will crash 
public Pages[] pages = new Pages[count];

public void setPages(Pages pages) {
    this.pages[l] = pages;
    l++;
}
```

But this all points to a bigger issue with your code. Let's say you get your code running 100%. Well now you're relying on the JSON to always always always return a value greater than 0. And I'm not sure the purpose of your code but maybe that will be the case. And in your production version of your code you will always get a value greater than 0. Maybe so, but in that rare case, if you ever get a 0 from the JSON it will crash. No matter what. Again I'm not sure what will cause you to get a 0  from the JSON in real world scenario but if you ever ever get a 0 it will crash. My recommendations would be to wrap the set pages: void in a try and catch